# Play Framework 2.3 Scala - Serialize Map[(String,CaseClass1),(CaseClass2,CaseClass3)] to JSon

Tags: json, playframework, playframework-2.0

I have a Map which consists of tuple `(String,CaseClass1)` as a key and tuple `(CaseClass2,CaseClass3)` as value.

I created implicit Writers for each case class:

```
  implicit val caseClass1Writes = Json.writes[CaseClass1]
  implicit val caseClass2Writes = Json.writes[CaseClass2]
  implicit val caseClass3Writes = Json.writes[CaseClass3]
```

I tries to create another case class which contains all those tuples

`TupleCaseClass(key:(String,CaseClass1),value:(CaseClass2,CaseClass3))` and then create implicit writer for this class, but the result is still the same :(

```
No Json serializer found for type Map[(String,CaseClass1),(CaseClass2,CaseClass3)]. Try to implement an implicit Writes or Format for this type.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, I had no other choice, but writing an implicit method which will transform `Map[(String,CaseClass1),(CaseClass2,CaseClass3)]` to `List[TupleCaseClass]`

```
val map:Map[(String,CaseClass1),(CaseClass2,CaseClass3)] = some map
```

can be easily converter to List of case Classes using foldLeft method

```
val list:List[TupleCaseClass] = map.foldLeft(List[TupleCaseClass]()){(l,t)=>l :+ ToupleCaseClass(t._1,t._2)}
```

and then `Json.toJson(list)`

This solution is ugly, I would expect Json parser to take care of such primitve structures like Tuples or Maps.

Hope it would be helpful for someone in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have tuples in your `TupleCaseClass`, Play does not implicitly understand how to write this (there's no obvious way to write a tuple of two custom objects).  You have to provide two more implicits to handle the tuples, e.g.

```
implicit val keyWrites = new Writes[(String, CaseClass1)]{
  def writes(o: (String, CaseClass1)) = Json.obj(o._1 -> o._2)
}

implicit val valueWrites = new Writes[(CaseClass2, CaseClass3)]{
  def writes(o: (CaseClass2, CaseClass3)) = Json.obj("caseClass2" -> o._1, "caseClass3" -> o._2)
}
```

Comment: unfortunately, it also did not help, so I wrote some implicit method which converts Map to list of case classes